# Unable to install heroku-toolbelt on linux mint 14?

Tags: heroku

I have deployed portfolio app recently. Now, I want to update my app through different machine(linux mint 14).So, to update my app, definitely I need to install heroku toolbelt on my machine, latter on I can go forward with remaining things. Right?.
But, here my problem is "I can't install heroku toolbelt on my machine".

While installing process it is showing up the following error

```
 wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
    This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
    You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
    --2013-11-14 16:23:38--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
    Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 174.129.17.173, 23.21.198.2, 54.243.76.97
    Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|174.129.17.173|:443... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 1737 (1.7K) [application/octet-stream]
    Saving to: `STDOUT'

    100%[=======================================>] 1,737       --.-K/s   in 0s      

    2013-11-14 16:23:39 (22.2 MB/s) - written to stdout [1737/1737]

    OK
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                     
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                                 
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                                  
    Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia InRelease                               
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                         
    Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease                       
    Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease                              
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                         
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                                
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                              
    Get:1 http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal InRelease                           
    Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
    Get:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia Release.gpg [198 B]                   
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg                            
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                               
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                    
    Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease                                     
    Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release [49.6 kB]             
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release                                
    Get:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia Release [18.6 kB]                     
    Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]             
    Get:7 http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal Release.gpg                         
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                               
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages                  
    Get:8 http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg [490 B]                         
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                   
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages                         
    Get:9 http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal Release                             
    Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal Release                               
    E: GPG error: http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package heroku-toolbelt
```

So, After that 
I have followed the Google search,stack overflow search to resolve the problem.I am trying to install it through some other process which is identified through stack overflow, but  still it is not solved my problem and it is showing up error with libnss3 dependencies as

```
libnss3-1d : Depends: libnss3 (= 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu7) but 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I have replaced this libnss3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu7 with libnss3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 in order to support Google-chrome browser.
But it is not supported for Heroku. If i will install the previous versioned libnss3 then i should remove google-chrome.I need google chrome because it provides best developer tool support for debugging and profiling the app.

Please help me to resolve this installing heroku-toolbelt problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

And then add the Heroku CLI to your PATH using:

```
   echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the same but getting following errors like  "This script requires superuser access to install software.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
sh: 7: [[: not found
sh: 31: [[: not found
Installation complete" for the 1st command.Then I executed the 2nd. To test the heroku, i just used heroku on the command line, then it returns "/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory". Now, what should i do.... thanks

Comment: I've done this, it still gives me the same error. Is the path incorrect? Does it matter which directory you're in when running the installation command?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error "/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory" means you need to install Ruby.